# Controlling a JavaFX ContextMenu connected to a TextField with the arrow keys

Tags: java, javafx, focus, contextmenu, textfield

I am trying to make an autocomplete style **TextField** that uses a **ContextMenu** to display the suggestions below the TextField. I would like for the ContextMenu to be displayed when a user presses the down key while focus is on the TextField. This is my current solution:

```
setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        System.out.println("pressed " + event.getCode());
        switch (event.getCode()) {
            case DOWN:
                if(getText().length()>0) {
                    if (!suggestionMenu.isShowing()) {
                        suggestionMenu.show(AutoCompleteTextField.this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                    }
                    suggestionMenu.getSkin().getNode().lookup(".menu-item").requestFocus();
                }
                break;
        }
    });
```

> *Source: [ContextMenu and programmatically selecting an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332981/contextmenu-and-programmatically-selecting-an-item/27333547#27333547)*

Using this code, the down arrow always "selects" (colours blue) the first item in the list. The problem is that sometimes (seems random to me), the second arrow key-press will not yield any response in the ContextMenu - the first item will stay selected. After that press, it will always work fine.

I would also prefer that pressing up while having the first element selected would hide the ContextMenu, and that space would not fire the *onAction* method of the **MenuItem**s, though I don't really understand how the focus/event listening for this menu works. It seems like the keyboard has two focuses at once - up/down, spacebar and enter on the ContextMenu, while everything else goes to the TextField.

Edit:
Here is a complete example. When showing the ContextMenu using the arrow down key, sometimes it will cause the problematic behaviour, other times not.

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        AutoCompleteTextField actf = new AutoCompleteTextField();
        pane.setTop(actf);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**AutoCompleteTextField.java**

```
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class AutoCompleteTextField extends TextField {
    private ContextMenu suggestionMenu;

    public AutoCompleteTextField(){
        super();
        suggestionMenu = new ContextMenu();
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            CustomMenuItem item = new CustomMenuItem(new Label("Item "+i), true);
            item.setOnAction(event -> {
                setText("selected");
                positionCaret(getText().length());
                suggestionMenu.hide();
            });
            suggestionMenu.getItems().add(item);
        }

        textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(getText().length()>0){
                if (!suggestionMenu.isShowing())
                    suggestionMenu.show(AutoCompleteTextField.this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            } else {
                suggestionMenu.hide();
            }
        });

        setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            System.out.println("pressed " + event.getCode());
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case DOWN:
                    if(getText().length()>0) {
                        if (!suggestionMenu.isShowing()) {
                            suggestionMenu.show(AutoCompleteTextField.this, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                        }
                        suggestionMenu.getSkin().getNode().lookup(".menu-item").requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I added an example.

Comment: ooookay .. can't reproduce the not-selection, but had seen it, so seems to be very random ;) As to the details of your requirements: a bit hard to follow - in your shoes I would have a look at ContextMenuSkin and ContextMenuContent,  latter is doing all the key bindings, selections and such - you might be able to hook into them (if your context isn't too complex like having multiple levels of submenus).

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59688014/is-there-a-way-to-access-contextmenu-scroll-arrows-scroll-bar-javafx) and the `ContextMenuContent.class`.

`ContextMenuContent`, as kleopatra suggested, does most of the key bindings. Inside, there is a method called `requestFocusOnIndex()` that allowed me to get rid that weird behavior.

So your code could be:

```
textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event->{
    if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
        if(!suggestionMenu.isShowing())
            suggestionMenu.show(textField, Side.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        suggestionMenuKeyBindings = (ContextMenuContent) suggestionMenu.getSkin().getNode();
        suggestionMenuKeyBindings.requestFocusOnIndex(0);
    }
});
```

Also, you will need to put

```
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED
```

When compiling AND running, otherwise you may get an IllegalAccessError

Answer (score 0):

I workaround the problem in Kotlin by opening a "fake" ContextMenu in the AutoCompleteTextField init-block and closing it after one millisecond in other coroutine.

You can do that in Java as well with a new thread. Hope it helps!

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    Platform.runLater {
        suggestionMenu.items.add(MenuItem("fake"))
        suggestionMenu.show(this@AutoCompleteTextField, Side.BOTTOM, 0.0, 0.0)
    }
    delay(1)
    Platform.runLater {
        suggestionMenu.hide()
    }
}
```