# Is there a way to access ContextMenu scroll arrows (scroll bar) ? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, autocomplete, contextmenu

I implement autocomplete textfield based on this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40369435/9047625

I use ContextMenu which height is long enough so ~15 items can be visible at a time, when there are more items available arrows show at the bottom and on the top of the contextmenu.

The problem i have is that when i scroll down on the items and i input some other words my context menu remains scrolled down, and i have to scroll it up manually to show the items even if there is only 1 item.

I tried on different ways to access the scroll bar of ContextMenu, so i can scroll it to top every time i input a new character in the field, but i couldn't figure a way to do so..

Is there any way to scroll up the contextmenu or to set the focus to the first element (top) whenever i input something in the field for auto completion ?

I hope i managed to explain my problem correctly and i'm thankful for the replies in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContextMenu` keeps an up and down arrows as a special type of `MenuItem` called `ArrowMenuItem`. The structure goes like this:

```
ContextMenu > ContextMenuSkin > ContextMenuContent > ArrowMenuItem
```

`ArrowMenuItem` is a non-static package-private class. `ContextMenuContent` has two instances of this class: `upArrow` and `downArrow` and these two instances are shown only when the items can't fit in the `ContextMenu`. `ContextMenuContent` uses a `Timeline` to scroll the `ContextMenu`, so when an `ENTERED` type `MouseEvent` is fired on any of those arrow items, the `Timeline` starts scrolling the content up or down based on hovered `ArrowMenuItem`. The `Timeline` stops when the mouse exits that region.
`ContextMenuContent` has a method `scroll` that is all you need, but unfortunately, this method is not public.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Extend `ContextMenuSkin`, `ContextMenuContent` to expose the method `scroll`. In this way, you can call lookup `ContextMenuContent` from the skin and use that method to scroll all the way up or down.
2. Use `menu-up-arrow` and `menu-down-arrow` style classes to lookup the arrow nodes. Once you get the arrow node, you can stimulate a mouse `ENTERED` event to make the `ContextMenu` scroll up or down. Note that in this way the user has to wait until the scrolling finishes since the `Timeline` has a fixed scrolling rate. Then you need to consume this event after the scrolling is over.
   Sample code:

```java
ContextMenuSkin skin = (ContextMenuSkin) contextMenu.getSkin();
Node up = skin.getNode().lookup(".menu-up-arrow");
Node down = skin.getNode().lookup(".menu-down-arrow");
MouseEvent enteredEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, ...); // the remaining parameters
if (shouldScrollUp) {
    up.fireEvent(enteredEvent);
} else {
    down.fireEvent(enteredEvent);
}
// consume the event after scroll is over
```

3. Using Reflection:

```java
private static void scrollContextMenuUp(ContextMenu contextMenu) {
    try {
        ContextMenuSkin skin = (ContextMenuSkin) contextMenu.getSkin();
        ContextMenuContent content = (ContextMenuContent) skin.getNode();
        Method method = content.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("scroll", double.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(content, 12.0); // change this double value to scroll more
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to scroll due to: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I already extended ContextMenu from my custom context menu so I can set its height. Im not exactly sure what do u mean by extending ContextMenu Skin, ContextMenuContent since I can't extend multiple classes from my class?

Comment: Sorry for posting double, I'm on my phone, I really would love to make first solution work, and if I can't figure it out I will go with second, I just wanted to ask u how do I know when the scroll is actually over and I can consume the event? And thank you very much I've been struggling with this really for a long time, I'm really thankful for ur time to answer this

Comment: and for 1st solution it seems like scroll method has default access modifier so i cannot access it from different package.. :/

Comment: You can override `createDefaultSkin()` to return your own `ContextMenuSkin`. What version of JDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using jdk1.8.0_221. I see i can override createDefaultSkin() from my class that extends ContextMenu(which i made so i can set the height of the contextmenu). But i don't understand how can i access the scroll method.. thanks again for ur help i really appreciate it

Comment: I didn't notice that `ContextMenuSkin` has a private final `ContextMenuContent` which you can't change by extending. If you have no option, you can access `scroll` method by using reflection.

Comment: I edited the answer to include the code that uses reflection

Comment: Thanks a bounch! It worked :)  I'm deeply grateful to your time and patience!