# Using ContextMenu by releasing mouse button on an item

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, contextmenu

I couldn't really explain the question in the title.

What I want to do is that when a right mouse-press (not click!) is performed on a element a ContextMenu shows up (this part is easy). The problem is that when I (still holding the mouse button) move my cursor over the items they do not get highlighted and when I release the mouse button the MenuItem does not get selected. The ContextMenu does not seem to be aware of the cursor until I release the button from the press that opened it.

Basically a right mouse-press shows a ContextMenu and releasing the button over a MenuItem should select it. What I am talking about is available in basically every single program (browsers, IDEs, etc.).

```java
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
var mi1 = new MenuItem("Item 1");
mi1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Item 1"));
var mi2 = new MenuItem("Item 2");
mi2.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Item 2"));
contextMenu.getItems().addAll(mi1, mi2);

node.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
        contextMenu.show(node, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
});
```

Comment: Are you wanting to open the `ContextMenu` with the right mouse button, then while the mouse button is still pressed, release it over a `MenuItem` to fire it?

Comment: @DustinR Exactly! I also want the MenuItem to be highlighted ("focused") when the cursor is over it but that's not as important as the firing.

Comment: why do you want to confuse your users? the open mouse gesture for opening a context menu is OS dependent ..

Comment: It's like that on basically all Linux-based OSes, Windows and Mac. It shouldn't confuse anybody, just introduce more convenience because it works like other parts of the OS.

Comment: I used "hacky" methods of casting and looking up elements and while it seems a bit off, it works as I want it to and is far better than nothing. Might publish my solution if I can make it good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the `ContextMenu` when the right mouse button is clicked, the following will work.

```
        node.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            // If the menu is already open, then close it to avoid multiple
            if (cm.isShowing()) {
                cm.hide();
            }
            if (e.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                cm.show(stage);
            }
        });
```

As for then moving the mouse to a `MenuItem` and releasing the already pressed secondary mouse button to activate the `MenuItem`, this doesn't seem to be supported.

The `MenuItem`'s onAction is called by default even if the `MouseButton` is the secondary `MouseButton`, so unless you implement your own control, then this will be the best you can get.

I've included a complete runnable example of the behavior that I've described below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button buttonTest = new Button("Right-Click me!");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(buttonTest));
        stage.show();

        ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem miTest = new MenuItem("Test");
        miTest.setOnAction(e -> new
                Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION,"Test").showAndWait());
        cm.getItems().add(miTest);
        buttonTest.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (cm.isShowing()) {
                cm.hide();
            }
            if (e.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                cm.show(stage);
                e.consume();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: If you can give an example of an application that exhibits this behavior, maybe I could look into it further and see if there's an equivalent implementation in JavaFX. You mention IDEs, browsers, etc. but I'm unable to reproduce what I think you're describing.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer does not add anything to the question. My code already shows the context menu on secondary mouse-press and does it in a much simpler way with same unwanted end result of the ContextMenu not detecting movements over it while the button is held.

Comment: As `MenuItem` doesn't have a `.addEventFilter` and only a `.setOnAction` I don't think that you can get the behavior you want without some serious tweaking. You'd have to create your own version of  `ContextMenu` from what I can tell.

Comment: I tried some workarounds with suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332981/contextmenu-and-programmatically-selecting-an-item but it got complex and messy so I thought I'd ask here. My initial thought was to add an event listener to the scene property of ContextMenu (getScene).

Comment: I also found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315774/javafx-2-0-activating-a-menu-like-a-menuitem/38525867#38525867 but couldn't succeed.

Comment: You could always hack a solution together by getting the X & Y of the MenuItem and adding event filter for MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, then call menuItem.fire() if the mouse were within bounds, but this just seems like over-engineering.